# Convert this Material UI hook api for Popovers to styled component API for Popovers

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, styled-components

I've edited my original post, so far I'm able to refactor away from hooks with this implementation, now, the behavior for moving the mouse cursor away does not close the popover.  This is what I have so far:

```
import React, { Fragment, useState } from 'react';
import propTypes from '../../propTypes';

import { Grid, Typography, Box, Popover } from '@material-ui/core';
import { makeStyles, styled } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import InfoIcon from '@material-ui/icons/InfoOutlined';
import { fade } from '@material-ui/core/styles/colorManipulator';

export const InfoIconWrapper = styled(InfoIcon)(({ theme }) => ({
  color: fade(theme.palette.black, 0.3),
}));

export const GridWrapper = styled(Grid)(({theme}) => ({
  pointerEvents: 'none',
  padding: theme.spacing(1),
}));

const DistributionLinePopover = ({ distributionLine }) => {
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = useState(null);

  const handlePopoverOpen = event => {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
    console.log("open")
  };

  const handlePopoverClose = () => {
    setAnchorEl(null);
    console.log("close")
  };

  const open = Boolean(anchorEl);

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Typography
        aria-owns={open ? 'mouse-over-popover' : undefined}
        aria-haspopup="true"
        onMouseEnter={handlePopoverOpen}

      >
        <InfoIconWrapper fontSize="small" />
      </Typography>
      <Popover
        id="mouse-over-popover"
        open={open}
        anchorEl={anchorEl}
        anchorOrigin={{
          vertical: 'bottom',
          horizontal: 'left',
        }}
        transformOrigin={{
          vertical: 'top',
          horizontal: 'left',
        }}
        onClose={handlePopoverClose}
        // onMouseLeave={handlePopoverClose}
        disableRestoreFocus
      >
        <GridWrapper container>
```

What can I do to have the popover close when the user moves their mouse away from it? onExit, onExited, onExiting does not produce the desired behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles'`

Then, your styles are defined as such:

```
const styles = theme => ({
    ...
});
```

Your `className` attributes will be `className={classes.popover}` (or whichever you're using). Note, `classes` is passed into your component, so you would obtain it from the signature, i.e. `function Component({classes}) { ... }`

Finally, you export your class as such:

`export default withStyles(styles)(Component)`

Comment: he asked for a solution with styled-components library

Comment: They're using MaterialUI and their constraint is to "not use hooks."

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work.  We can't use HOC wrappers either.  I'll edit my original post to show you what I have so far.  So far, I've gotten it to work except the onMouseLeave event doesn't work unless the user clicks away from the popover.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the solution to the updated post is to replace onClose with onMouseOut.